# Passing a variable into a jquery load() function syntax

Tags: jquery, load

I am trying to find out how to pass that a variable string staffID into an id selector in the load() function. Here is the piece of code:

```
  $('li.staffAsset').click(function () {
    var staffID = $(this).attr("id");
    openDialog('#descrDialog');
    $('#staffDescr p').load('/staffDescr.html $("#" + staffID)');
    });
```

This doesn't work. Basically there are divs with id="staffID" inside the staffDescr.html.
I just can't seem to find the proper syntax to pass that variable string as a proper id into the load() function.
Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 3):

You don't pass the dollar function into the string. Just use this:

```
$('#staffDescr p').load('/staffDescr.html #' + staffID);
```

See the documentation: **[Loading Page Fragments](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments)**.

---

Also, there's no need for `$(this).attr("id")`. Just use `this.id`:

```
$('li.staffAsset').click(function () {
    openDialog('#descrDialog');
    $('#staffDescr p').load('/staffDescr.html #' + this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You messed the quotes. To simply put the id in your string you might replace

```
$('#staffDescr p').load('/staffDescr.html $("#" + staffID)');
```

with

```
$('#staffDescr p').load('/staffDescr.html $("#"' + staffID+')');
```

But you probably want

```
$('#staffDescr p').load('/staffDescr.html #' + staffID);
```

if you're trying to [load a page fragment](http://api.jquery.com/load/).